# Message dropdown descriptions and actions for owners (and mods?) are incorrect

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, chat-pins

I found at least two situations where the message dropdowns show incorrect status and action description.

#### Scenario 1

1. Pin a message.
2. Unpin it and clear stars for it.
3. Reload the page.

The message dropdown now says:

> You have starred and pinned this message.
>
> - Unstar as interesting
> - Unpin this message

Additionally, a star is shown next to the message.

However, the message is neither starred or pinned -- and the sidebar confirms.

[image: A clearly unpinned message is reported to be pinned.]

---

#### Scenario 2

1. Somebody else pins a message.

The message dropdown now says:

> This message has been pinned.
>
> - Pin this message
> - Star as interesting

The message, however, is already pinned.

[image: A clearly unpinned message is reported to be pinned.]

Comment: To clarify I didn't clear the stars in the picture of scenario 1.

Comment: We can't repro scenario 1.

Answer (score 2):

Scenario 2:

The pins may be slightly confusing - it is reporting separately because *you* haven't pinned it; underneath, pins are similar to flags and stars, but maybe it should handle this more elegantly (or hide this minor implementation detail).

Scenario 1:

Hmm... that is odd; I wonder if that is the old enemy: cache. I'll double-check whether this is handled accurately when cached. Added to my list ;p

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?